# How to use df.apply to switch between columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
df_H = pd.DataFrame( {'L0': np.random.randn(100),
                      'OneAndZero': np.random.randn(100),
                      'OneAndTwo': np.random.randn(100),
                      'GTwo': np.random.randn(100),
                      'Decide': np.random.randn(100)})
```

I would like to create a new column named Result, which depends on the value of the column Decide. So if the value in Decide is less than 0, I would like Result to have the corresponding value of the row in L0. If the value on the row in Decide is between 1 and 0, it should grab the value in OneAndZero, between 1 and 2, it should grab OneAndTwo and if the value of decide is > 2, then it should grab GTwo.

How would one do this with df.apply since I have only seen examples with fixed values and not values from other columns?

Comment: Please share what you tried so far - hint `np.where` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it is Good Friday, we can try the following. Else it is a commonly asked question.

```
c1=df_H['Decide'].le(0)
c2=df_H['Decide'].between(0,1)
c3=df_H['Decide'].between(1,2)
c4=df_H['Decide'].gt(2)
cond=[c1,c2,c3,c4]
choices=[df_H['L0'],df_H['OneAndZero'],df_H['OneAndTwo'],df_H['GTwo']]
         
df_H['Result']=np.select(cond,choices)
df_H
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use apply

```
def choose_res(x):
    if x['Decide'] <= 0:
        return x['L0']
    if 0 < x['Decide'] <= 1:
        return x['OneAndZero']
    if 1 < x['Decide'] <= 2:
        return x['OneAndTwo']
    if x['Decide'] > 2:
        return x['GTwo']

df_H['Result'] = df_H.apply(axis=1, func=choose_res, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 0):

df.iloc

```
df_H.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
for i in range(len(df_H)):
    a = df_H['Decide'].iloc[i]
    if 0 <= a <=1 :
      b = df_H['OneAndZero'].iloc[i]
      df_H.loc[i,'Result']= b
    if 1.1 <= a <= 2:
      b = df_H['OneAndTwo'].iloc[i]
      df_H.loc[i,'Result']= b
```

maybe you can try this way.

**df_apply**
if you want to use apply..

create the function that have the condition, and the output,
then used this code:

df_H['Result'] = df_H.apply(your function name)